# What is a good general fitness routine?

Tags: routine

I'm looking for a good all-purpose fitness routine.

In the past I have followed training plans for triathlons, power lifting, and P90X.  At the moment I'm not training for anything specific, but would like to stay in good shape.  The areas I would like to cover are strength, speed, endurance, flexibility, balance, and coordination.  I exercise for one hour a day, every day of the week.  I would also like to occasionally incorporate sports and outdoor activities.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to organize these in a week or a month, and in each session?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you're looking for the entire package! To do this you're going to have to take things phase by phase and just repeat it over time. Take a look at a program by a guy named Elliot Hulse. It's called "Lean Hybrid Muscle". It mixes strength training, hypertrophy training and athletic training all into one. It works in 2 phases.

Phase 1:
Power building &
Athletic Training

Phase 2:
Strength Training &
Athletic Training

Now each phase is 3 weeks (intense training) + 1 deload week (3 days of High intensity Interval Training but no weights). The program is 5 days a week, so on your off days you can participate in your outdoor sportive activities (a game of ball, or a simple hike in the woods), and on the deload week you can focus on your coordination and flexibility. repeat Phase 1 about three times (takes 3 months), then do the same for phase 2 (also 3 months)

I have done this program myself and have gotten great results in my athletic performance and physical appearance.

"A functional body will always look good, but a good looking body may not be functional" - No Idea...

Good Luck!